# Laravel Event Sourcing (Spatie) - How to deal with more complex business rules

Tags: php, laravel, event-sourcing

I have currently started in the world of event-sourcing, using spaties' package [spatie/laravel-event-sourcing](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-event-sourcing/v1/introduction).

After following the basic setup and guides as well as reading/watching a lot of other event sourcing guides I have got a basic understanding but am struggling to understand how more complex business rules should be implemented.

### Simple rule - bank balance example

The below example is straight forward and makes total sense. You subtract money from the balance for each event. If you go below a threshold then an exception is thrown prior to being allowed to go any lower.

```
public function subtractMoney(int $amount)
{
    if (!$this->hasSufficientFundsToSubtractAmount($amount)) {
        $this->recordThat(new AccountLimitHit());

        if ($this->needsMoreMoney()) {
            $this->recordThat(new MoreMoneyNeeded());
        }

        $this->persist();

        throw CouldNotSubtractMoney::notEnoughFunds($amount);
    }

    $this->recordThat(new MoneySubtracted($amount));
}

protected function applyMoneySubtracted(MoneySubtracted $event)
{
    $this->balance -= $event->amount;

    $this->accountLimitHitInARow = 0;
}
```

### More complex - additional attributes

In the above example, we only have a single attribute (amount).

In my use case, my aggregate root is product inventory. I want the aggregate to be able to capture all inventory movements across different storage locations. i.e.

- stock is received into a location
- stock is moved from one location A to location B
- stock is assigned to order 1 from location A
- stock is picked for order 1 from location A
- stock is packed into shipment package Z for order 1

Doing the projections is actually quite simple. For example, my inventory projector shows each product in each location and how much inventory is received, allocated etc..

```
public function onStockReceived(StockReceived $event, string $aggregateUuid)
{
    $inventory = Inventory::firstOrNew([
        'product_id' => $aggregateUuid,
        'location_id' => $event->locationId
    ]);

    $inventory->received += $event->amount;

    $inventory->save();
}
```

My issue with this is back in the aggregate root when trying to determine business rules. It feels like I have to duplicate the code within my projector to be able to check against the data in the events.

In the below example I want to make sure that I do not make more stock available than what has been received. i.e. do not go below 0. This starts to feel quite complex and duplicating counts that are already stored within my projector.

```
public function makeStockAvailable(int $amount, $locationId)
{
    if($this->hasInsufficientStockToMakeAvailable($amount, $locationId)){
        throw CouldNotMakeStockAvailable::insufficientStock($amount, $this->locations[$locationId]['received']);
    }

    $this->recordThat(new StockMadeAvailable($amount, $locationId));

    return $this;
}

public function applyStockMadeAvailable(StockMadeAvailable $event)
{
    $this->stockMadeAvailableInLocation($event->amount, $event->locationId);

    $this->availableStockTotal($event->amount);
}

private function stockMadeAvailableInLocation($amount, $locationId)
{
    $this->locations[$locationId]['received'] = $this->locations[$locationId]['received'] ?? 0;

    $this->locations[$locationId]['received'] -= $amount;

    $this->locations[$locationId]['available'] = $this->locations[$locationId]['available'] ?? 0;

    $this->locations[$locationId]['available'] += $amount;
}

private function availableStockTotal($amount)
{
    $this->received -= $amount;

    $this->available += $amount;
}

private function hasInsufficientStockToMakeAvailable($amount, $locationId): bool
{
    if(isset($this->locations[$locationId]['received'])){
        return $this->locations[$locationId]['received'] - $amount < 0;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I assume that it is not OK to use Eloquent within my aggregate root (looking up against projectors) as this will cause a huge number of database queries and im not sure the AR should depend on the projection for decision making?

Also, it is not possible to add any business rules to my projectors as this is after the event has already been approved.

I really like spaties package as it makes the basics of event soucing easy, but it feels like there is quite a big jump to make it workable with more complex solutions.

### Example business logic to solve

```
public function moveAvailableStock(int $amount, $locationIdFrom, $locationIdTo)
{
    if(($available = $this->locations[$locationIdFrom]['available'] ?? 0) < $amount){
        throw CouldNotMoveStock::insufficientStock($amount, $available, $locationIdFrom);
    }

    $this->recordThat(new StockMoved($amount, $locationIdFrom, $locationIdTo));

    return $this;
}
```

When I am replaying events I need to store each movent of stock through its status (received, available, allocated) as well as the location in which they are stored. I am currently doing this with an array stored to a private variable ($locations) and it works, but it does feel like:

a) it will not scale. The array could grow to thousands of elements depending on how many locations are used.

b) it could get complicated very quickly. This is just one rule of many.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue here that you are skipping an important fact in `event-sourcing` which is `events` storage.

Inside your projection, it looks like you are storing entities. Projections are basically `Listeners` that react to something happened.

In general, you would need to apply the following scenario

1. Compose your Aggregate Root from list of events (empty if no events yet)
2. Apply the Business Logic inside your AR (this should be the source of truth for business invariant)
3. Record an Event like `StockMadeAvailable`
4. Store your events in an `Event Store` -> which could be `MySQL`
5. You can use your projections to listen to your events or external events and update your Read models,they are basically DB tables developed in a way to provide high performance queries

Also, Spatie provides an infrastructure for `Event Sourcing` but still the composition of your own Aggregates/Entities/Business invariants depends on your business needs

**Update #1**

Regarding this point - 
a) it will not scale. The array could grow to thousands of elements depending on how many locations are used.

- I would rather talk with business guys/domain experts to identify the peak and average amount of locations
- Using a set of entities and value objects might give you flexibility rather than `array $locations`, you can use hash maps or different data structures that fit your needs

b) it could get complicated very quickly. This is just one rule of many.
 - Generally, you would have different functions for each rule 
 - If it gets too complicated, why not have Domain `Rules` same idea as Domain `Exceptions`

It's just ideas that might help.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to use the events storage as the source of truth here. I am generating the events and they can be replyed to build the projections. That all seems fine. 

My issue at this point is how I store fairly complex models and logic within the events and then query them in the aggregate root.

I will add an example to the main question

Comment: @AdamLambert I see, "It feels like I have to duplicate the code within my projector to be able to check against the data in the events." this part was bit consufing. I updated my reply :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and edit to this. I have upvoted you but I am not sure I am really asking the right question to get the answer I need. I have tried again here with a better example!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455116/laravel-event-sourcing-spatie-using-projections-within-business-rules